# How do I access the Save pop-up on older files

Tags: blend-files, versions, saving

I just switched to Blender 2.91 and I am having a problem: when I close a project I did with 2.90 I do not get the option to save. Saving manually does work, but it adds a file called quit.blend every time. What should I do

Comment: quit.blender is a copy of the file that was last opened, in case you need to recover the last session.

Comment: The save prompt when you exit blender can be enabled/disabled in the preferences, (Load & Save tab). Have you checked if it's turned on?

Comment: @Blunder It is on, and I only have the problem when I am using older files.